# What dependencies am I missing for my linux kernel to execute "make menuconfig"?

Tags: kernel, dependencies

I am at my wit's end at finding out what necessary dependencies I need for my Linux Kernel 5.14 for Ubuntu 21.04. I am using a virtual machine in VirtualBox.

I initially used "sudo apt-get install gcc" and "sudo apt-get install make" then used

"sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev flex bison openssl libssl-dev dkms libelf-dev libudev-dev libpci-dev libiberty-dev autoconf"

to resolve error 127 but then got error 1. What additional commands do I need to do to get my kernel working for make configure?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the errors are?

Comment: `sudo apt install build-essential` will provide the packages which make gcc functional.

Comment: I fixed the problem, I didn't mention the terminal being too small for menuconfig so I changed the size of the terminal.